# Sonata Admin: isGranted() always returns true in Admin class, but correct boolean in template

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm using `SonataAdminBundle` and `SonataUserBundle` in a `Symfony 2` project. The installed packages are:

```
$ composer show | grep symfony
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle             1.7.7              This Bundle provides various tools to rapidly develop RESTful API's with Symfony
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle             v1.3.6             Symfony FOSUserBundle
symfony/assetic-bundle                   v2.8.0             Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/css-selector                     v2.8.6             Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/dom-crawler                      v2.8.6             Symfony DomCrawler Component
symfony/monolog-bundle                   2.11.1             Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/polyfill-apcu                    v1.1.1             Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring                v1.1.1             Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle               v2.3.11            Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                          v2.7.13            The Symfony PHP framework

$ composer show | grep sonata
sonata-project/admin-bundle              2.3.10             Symfony SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/block-bundle              2.2.15             Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     1.0.7              Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle               2.3.11             Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.0.2              Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.4              Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine ORM into the SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.1.10             Symfony SonataEasyExtendsBundle
sonata-project/exporter                  1.4.1              Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/google-authenticator      1.0.2              Library to integrate Google Authenticator into a PHP project
sonata-project/user-bundle               2.2.5              Symfony SonataUserBundle
```

The roles in the `security.yml` configuration file:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Logged in with a user that has `ROLE_ADMIN` only, the following dumps from my `UserAdmin` class:

```
dump($this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH'));
dump($this->isGranted('ROLE_BLA_BLA_BLA'));
dump($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER'));
```

print in Symfony toolbar (on `dev` environment)

```
true
true
true
```

While if I put the dumps in an overridden Sonata template like `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/[anytemplate].html.twig`,

```
{{ dump(is_granted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')) }}
{{ dump(is_granted('ROLE_BLA_BLA_BLA')) }}
{{ dump(is_granted('ROLE_USER')) }}
```

the correct values are returned.

```
false
false
true
```

I got into this because this line here, in `SonataUserBundle`, had no effect: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php#L95

The `isGranted()` usage is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html#usage

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @mickadoo's comment I noticed that I had the default handler `sonata.admin.security.handler.noop`, which is said to always return `true`, whatever that means. I set it up with `sonata.admin.security.handler.role` and created some roles (`ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST` and `ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_VIEW`) and now it returns the correct value for `$this->isGranted('LIST')` or `$this->isGranted('VIEW')`, but always returns `false` for `$this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')` or `$this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')`.

How can I check this roles?

Comment: Did you set your access_decision_strategy to unanimous as mentioned here?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html#id1

Comment: Thank you! It didn't changed much, but helped me notice I was using the default handler `sonata.admin.security.handler.noop`. I edited the question to provide more information.

Comment: Nice to hear it helped you. Like I said, I'm not experienced with sonata but I don't see any usages checking purely roles in the docs page. Have you tried `$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))`? If you just want to check if a user has a role you could always create a service using the `RoleHierarchy` to check if the reachable roles contains the role you want to check, but maybe this isn't the cleanest way. If you could debug and check which of the `AccessDecisionManager` voters is returning false it might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Generic, non-entity roles**, like `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, `ROLE_{CUSTOM_STRING}` should be checked using the default Symfony security context.

In the `Admin` class:

```
$securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');

if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    // Your PHP code here
}
```

In `Twig` template:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    Your HTML/Twig content here.
{% endif %}
```

**Entity actions roles** like `ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST`, `ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_VIEW`, `ROLE_{CUSTOM_SONATA_ADMIN_SERVICE_NAME}_{ACTION}` can be checked using the Sonata Admin helper or the Symfony security context.

In the `Admin` class:

```
// Using Symfony security context
$securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');

if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST')) {
    // your code here
}

// Using Sonata helper for shorter syntax
if ($this->isGranted('LIST')) {
    // your code here
}
```

In `Twig` template:

```
<!-- Using Symfony security context -->
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST') %}
    Your HTML/Twig content here.
{% endif %}

<!-- Using Sonata helper -->
{% if admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
    Your HTML/Twig content here.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: By using `$securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');` in an Admin class, I get an error: `You have requested a non-existent service "security.context".` Please advise

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. `security.context` is used until Symfony 2.5. Since Symfony 2.6 the service `security.context` is depricated, and now we have to use `security.authorization_checker` instead. Like this; `$securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker');`

Comment: I get this error when try using authorization_checker in a Admin class "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL in . (which is being imported from "app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "sonata_admin" type." and the token is NULL, what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me in sonata admin and Symfony 4:

```
/**
 * @param string $role
 * @return bool
 */
protected function checkUserHasRole(string $role): bool
{

    $securityContext = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker');
    try {
        return $securityContext->isGranted($role);
    } catch (AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about a Symfony 2 project (I have updated it to reflect this). Your answer might be useful for someone using Symfony 4 though. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Am working on a project right now and it seems isGranted is doing that in Admin classes.
Workaround I found is this in the Admin class:

```
if ($this->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles()[0] == 'ROLE_EMPLOYEE') {}
```

It returns the roles (without inheritance) you have assigned upon User creation.
You will of course need to cater for inheritance, so you will have to list all roles you want to allow or disallow, whichever is less to list.
Check getUser() is not empty and getRoles() returns an array.